# Issue with MYSQL PDO JOIN in Amchart

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with MYSQL PDO JOIN when I try to show a data inside of amchart graph bar.

When the JOIN is LEFT, the data returned is from my table 1 (ventas) and when the JOIN is RIGHT, the returned is from my table 2 (compras), but I need to show the UNION of both grouped monthly.

Here my code:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
    SUM(V.total) AS totalVM, //total amount in table 1
    DATE_FORMAT(V.f_rventa, '%M de %Y') AS grapNM, //date in table 1
    SUM(C.total) AS totalCM, //total amount in table 2
    DATE_FORMAT(C.f_compra, '%M de %Y') AS grapNM //date in table 2
    FROM VENTAS V RIGHT JOIN COMPRAS C  //HERE WHEN I CHANGE LEFT OR RIGHT IS THE ISSUE
    ON MONTH(V.f_rventa) AND YEAR(V.f_rventa) = MONTH(C.f_compra) AND YEAR(C.f_compra)
    GROUP BY MONTH(C.f_rventa) ASC, MONTH(C.f_compra) ASC");
    $sql->execute();
    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $totalVM = $row['totalVM'];
    $totalCM = $row['totalCM'];
    $grapNM = $row['grapNM'];

    $ventGast[] = array("MES"=>$grapNM, "ventas"=>$totalVM, "compras"=>$totalCM);

    }
```

Here a capture about:

table 1:

[table 1 ventas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6IL9.jpg)

table 2:

[table 2 compras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvU59.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing each month and year correctly in your join condition. You need to explicitly check month(date) = month(otherdate) and year(date) = year(otherdate):

```
ON MONTH(V.f_rventa) = MONTH(C.f_compra) AND YEAR(V.f_rventa) =  YEAR(C.f_compra)
```

Note that your group by code is also wrong - you aliased the table containing `f_rventa` to V, not C.

```
GROUP BY MONTH(V.f_rventa) ASC, MONTH(C.f_compra) ASC
```

Full query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(V.total) AS totalVM,
    DATE_FORMAT(V.f_rventa, '%M de %Y') AS grapNM, 
    SUM(C.total) AS totalCM, 
    DATE_FORMAT(C.f_compra, '%M de %Y') AS grapNM 
    FROM VENTAS V left JOIN COMPRAS C  
    ON MONTH(V.f_rventa) = MONTH(C.f_compra) AND YEAR(V.f_rventa) =  YEAR(C.f_compra)
    GROUP BY MONTH(V.f_rventa) ASC, MONTH(C.f_compra) ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcab22/6/0) with sample data.

Comment: Nice!, is working but how can I show only the current year?

Comment: add `AND YEAR(V.f_rventa) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())` to your join condition.